# Squid : Reverse proxy with IIS 10

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, squid

There is a website on ISS 10 on windows server 2019.
Default web site and one other.
I have not made any configuration of thoses websites and IIS. It's a crm product, all default settings.
I made a bind with https port and certificate on two websites.
On local network, when i go to https://local_net_adress, it redirect from default website to other site.
From Internet, when i go to https://public_adress, i m not redirected, it shows me default IIS webpage.

Here's my squid configuration from this website :
(squid in reverse proxy is operationnal for exchange webmail and many other apache websites.)

```
    # ----- xxxxxx -----
cache_peer xx.xx.xx.xx parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl sslflags=DONT_VERIFY_PEER login=PASS name=srv-xxx

acl myacl url_regex -i ^https://public_url/.*$

cache_peer_access srv-xxx allow myacl
cache_peer_access srv-xxx deny all

http_access allow myacl
never_direct allow myacl
miss_access allow myacl
```

Is issue on squid or IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok It's working now.
It was on IIS bindings.
To work, i had to delete binding from default website AND DO NOT PUT hostname on binding for the other website.
Problem solved.
[image: binding for website]